# Operation explanation of a low-swing differential receiver (amplifier)

Tags: transistors, amplifier, differential, receiver

The following figure shows an example of a low-swing differential receiver given in Hall's *Advanced Signal Integrity for High Speed Digital Designs*

[image]

However, I cannot figure out how this circuit works as a differential amplifier. Could anyone help me explain the function of this circuit?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it won't work.

Comment: @Andyaka You mean it is not a differential amplifier actually? Can you tell me why?

Comment: The circuit is really ambiguous in respect of biasing the current sources so really, it's not worth a shot at any explanation without a whole bunch of assumptions.

Comment: @Andyaka The current source is self-biased. There is an equilibrium: bias on the low side of equilibrium drives the current mirror harder and the bias rises. Bias on the high side of equilibrium drives the current sink harder and the bias falls.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because receivers for differential signals are NOT differential amplifiers. This is a common misconception. It is operating more like a Current Switch, or Crossing Detector. That is why matching the time delay when routing is so important because you have to keep that crossing section in the linear region or else the crossing detector will not be able to make out a logical 0 or 1 reliably.

My source is Lee Ritchey Right The First Time Chapter 31.

Admittedly I am lacking in fundamentals of semiconductor theory... But I will do my best to explain. Lee Ritchey explains with a VERY similar circuit except that the FETs are all "BJTs" instead, either way I am assuming the switching functionality is similar.

Vin and /Vin is your differential pair. One positive and one the inverse of the positive (unless you have LVDS). The MAIN and arguably ONLY benefit of differential pairs ON A PCB, is it will ignore ground offsets. So in a design with multiple units spread out very long distances, you will see noise from your grounds b/c there is a difference in potential between some 2 grounds in your system. Differential Pairs resolve this problem VERY effectively.

Ahh see, I have found an error in my explanation lol. I changed the following paragraph slightly:

The magic in your image, assuming the same switching operations as Lee's, is the 2 FETs above the Differential inputs, and the one FET below. In short, when Vin is high, it will steer all of the current from VDD down to the bottom FET, and then to Ground. If /Vin is high, then the Current will not be allowed to flow through the bottom FET, the FET has switched to blocking current flow, and essentially steers the current. I added an Amp Meter in my simulation to reflect that.

This is where the difference lies between a diff Amp and this Current Switch operating like a Crossing Detector (ill get to that part in a minute). In a Diff Amp, the current from the top splits into the 2 sides. This NEVER happens with any differential pair IC according to Lee Ritchey. The ground offsets is a bit more complicated.

So between the differential inputs, imagine the case where they are both switching at the same time. This would result in Vout either slowly going up or slowly going down as Vin rises/falls or /Vin falls/rises. The moment where Vout makes the transition from low to high or high to low is around the region when either the Vin is almost high or /Vin is almost high. So when you look at the differential inputs on a scope, what I just described is the crossing region! Its a crossing detector! That is why preserving the linear region when they cross is so integral to getting the right high/low at Vout. You are going to see bit errors if the inputs do not cross in that linear region.

I hope this helps, I am sorry I could not go into detail about the switching operations for the FETs.

I am adding two images of a simulation made in EveryCircuit. The voltages are not exact, nor are the FETs for real life use, but it gets the crossing effect idea across. Here is a link to the simulation, I do not believe you need an account: https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6077787273953280

Thank you Math Keeps Me Busy for the idea.

[image: Every Circuit Simulation Snapshot]

Comment: Thank you. I'd appreciate if you could explain more.

Comment: I simulated the circuit, and found that the falling edge of the output occurs when the inputs cross in value. However, I am not yet clear about characterizing when the rising edge of the output occurs. You may play with my simulation by clicking on the "simulate this circuit" link below the schematic. Perhaps you can adjust the MOSFET parameters or signal offsets so that both rising and falling edges occur at input crossings.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Quilty's answer provides insight into the workings of this differential receiver. Here is a simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPErOd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

The output does indeed switch values when the input and output voltages cross provided that M3 and M4 have the same threshold value, and that threshold value is in the right relationship with the input voltage ranges. Exactly what the threshold values need to be for the various transistors to ensure that output switching occurs at input voltage crossings, for a given range of input values, I have not yet completely determined.